# Why are the losses to the First Order not acknowledged?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

So towards the end of *The Last Jedi*

> The First Order has lost its leader and its command ship (which I believe also doubled as a construction yard) the new leader is emotionally unstable and inexperienced. This is kind of a big victory.

Yet none of this is mentioned among The Resistance. I know they're a little preoccupied, but this could at least affect morale. It could also have wider implications.

**Did I miss it, or is it just overlooked?**

Comment: "construction yard"?  /puzzle.

Comment: @Yakk not really a construction yard, but it did have a repair dock for the other star destroyers in the fleet.

Comment: Did the First Order *lose* its command ship? I got the impression it was heavily damaged, but still operational and likely can be repaired. It doesn't seem like there's gonna be any opposition anyway...

Comment: @Kat I think it is safe to say the command ship is not operational given it was in two pieces; sure there might still be lights on some (or even most) decks, but the ship can not operate as intended. And while the ship could be repaired that would take quite a bit of effort given its size and the fact that you would either need to bring all the supplies to the wreckage or tow its massive bulk to a repair yard... cause its not moving under its own power any time soon!

Comment: Supremacy "it's only a flesh wound"

Comment: Snoke is dead ? dead as in Darth Maul's dead after hacked in two pieces ?

Answer (score 10):

It's not entirely clear what the survivors of the attack have (or haven't) been told.

In the few short minutes that we see them after they board the Falcon, the only two people present that know that Snoke is dead are Finn and Rey. Finn is trying to make Rose comfortable and Rey spends her time repairing BB-8's antenna (as usual), has a ten-second chat with Poe and then a slightly longer conversation with Leia about Luke.

Comment: How does Finn know that Snoke is dead?

Comment: @Turion, my thought was the same. Finn doesn't know (he was in another part of the ship), and he and Rose made their own way down to Crait. The only one besides Rey who might know is Chewbacca, assuming Rey told him when he picked her up in the *Falcon*.

Answer (score 0):

Considering how fast the events of TLJ happen, it is probably just that no one has gotten around to actually debrief Rey who is the only one was there to see Snoke's death and Kylo's very tentative hold on power.

Add to this the fact that The Resistance just went through its own heavy losses and they probably are focusing on those first before they start asking what happened with the First Order.

It should be noted that at the start of Poe Dameron #31 Leia mentions being aware they have done some damage to the First Order, but in comparison to the damage done to The Resistance, well...she is not going to focus on the losses of the First Order that seems more stable.

[image]